# Active HGLRC and releasing it's HDC too early?

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl, gdi

In my engine, I support multiple windows by activating a single OpenGL context in turn for each window and drawing sequentially to it:

```
//ACTIVATE WINDOW 1
HDC deviceContext = GetDC(hWnd1);
wglMakeCurrent(deviceContext, renderContext);
ReleaseDC(hWnd, deviceContext);

//DRAW TO WINDOW 1

//ACTIVATE WINDOW 2
HDC deviceContext = GetDC(hWnd2);
wglMakeCurrent(deviceContext, renderContext);
ReleaseDC(hWnd, deviceContext);

//DRAW TO WINDOW 2

//SWAP BUFFERS FOR ALL WINDOWS

wglMakeCurrent(0, 0);
```

This works fine, however I'm now integrating a third party library which uses wglGetCurrentDC() to retrieve a handle to the current device context associated with the render context. As I call ReleaseDC before the library calls wglGetCurrentDC(), this seems to be failing, so in the end I think I'm going to have to cache a HDC for each window until it is destroyed and not call ReleaseDC until then.

The question is if the way I'm doing things at the moment (i.e. releasing a DC which is associated with an OpenGL rendering context before drawing) is technically allowed, or a side effect that just seems to work?

Comment: There's a window class style that might be particularly helpful for this sort of scenario. You should consider looking into `CS_OWNDC`. If you're using `CS_OWNDC` already (as is typical in OpenGL), then `ReleaseDC` is a no-op.

Comment: A quick and simple fix for my problem, excellent! If I keep my ReleaseDC calls I still get the same behaviour as before (as the handle associated with the render context still becomes invalid I believe, even if the actual DC is still the same), but now I can just remove them and not worry about when to release the DC at all. If you add this as an answer, I will mark it as correct if nobody answers the question, as it is a niche question and this actually solved my problem :)

Comment: I have an issue. If I remove the ReleaseDC calls, after around a minute the app becomes really slow and eventually I get a NULL handle from GetDC, so it looks like it’s creating a new device context each time and eventually running out of memory as I’m not releasing. The address of the handle returned is also different each time. I am pretty sure that the window class is setup and being used for each window correctly, as I changed the class style to CS_DROPSHADOW and the shadow looked a bit different. This could be why I still needed ReleaseDC in the comment above, but not sure what to try.

Comment: This is after using `CS_OWNDC`? That behavior is inconsistent, because that is supposed to create 1 DC per-window... no matter how many times you call `GetDC (hWnd)` it returns the same device context handle. That is why you don't ever have to release the device context, you're not really acquiring anything new.

Comment: Yep, this is when using CS_OWNDC and I confirmed that the window class is being used (I changed the cursor icon style to verify and also commented out the third party library integration just in case). Reading this page makes it seem as if I should only be using GetDC once even with a private context (there is a line that says "The application must retrieve the handle only once")? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162872(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Something I've just noticed - when caching a HDC created with CS_OWNDC, resizing the window will randomly (and very quickly) cause calls to `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)` to fail with GL_INVALID_OPERATION. Setting the window class style to 0 removed this issue, so in the end I went with caching a HDC without using CS_OWNDC. Not sure why that caused an issue, but this seems to work.